# Defining environment in TeXworks

Tags: packages, texworks

I have an environment defined in a file `env.sty` as well as the file `task.tex` which is based on that environment. How can I get `TeXworks` to read set the environment defined in a file, so that it is visible to `task.tex`?

`TeXworks` fails when rendering `task.tex` into PDF with `pdfTeX` with error `! LaTeX Error: Environment task undefined.` which means that it can't find user-defined environment in file `task.tex`.

Comment: Are they in the same directory? I'd post this as an answer but it seems too obvious.

Comment: @Emre: I think you could post it as an answer indicating the obvious solution... why not?

Comment: Did you add `\usepackage{env}`?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is that the files are in the same directory. Has this been done, or is there some obstacle?

Answer (score 0):

Could also try `\usepackage{<path>/env.sty}`, where `<path>` is either the relative or full path to the directory where the `env.sty` file is located.